# What should be the Vgs voltage?

Tags: voltage, mosfet, gate-driving

I know we can use a MOSFET with a Vgs equal to 10 or 15 V. If I have a MOSFET with a threshold value of 3 V, what should be the gate voltage of this MOSFET? Are higher voltages good, like 15 or 18 V, or can I just drive with 10 V?

Comment: You can look that up in the datasheet of the MOSFET you use. There are usually some figures relating Vgs to Rds(on), etc. The threshold value is just the voltage at which the MOSFET just (and barely) starts to conduct.

Comment: @ocrdu Is correct, but if you want something very general, low voltage, say 100 Vds MOSFETs are usually driven with 10 V. High voltage ones normally use 15 V.

Comment: Are you just using the MOSFET as a switch? or is it for some other purpose?

Answer (score 4):

You can find curves such as these from the datasheet:

[image]

[(From NTB5860NL Datasheet)](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ntb5860nl-d.pdf)

In a low speed switching application, a higher Vgs voltage will allow more current to pass through. Lower Rds(on) value is desireable in switching application, as the part will heat less.

For example Rds(on) that is given as a single value in catalogs and datasheets only applies to a specific Vgs.

Comment: The curves in a datasheet are only for a  Mosfet with only "typical" specs and at room temperature. Mosfets with Minimum or maximum specs or hot or cold are MUCH different.

Comment: True, also temperature and unit-to-unit variation have an effect. The effect of temperature is usually illustrated in the graphs too.

Comment: Higher Vgs also means more charge to deplete when switching off - so for high speed applications, it's not a good idea to go much past 12 V usually.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're talking about using the MOSFET as a switch. In that case, it's usually better to set \$V_{GS}\$ as high as possible, without being so large that it damages the transistor. This ensures the lowest possible \$R_{DS}\$.

So the question is, how high is too high? That's always a parameter listed in the "Absolute Maximum Ratings" section of the datasheet. Here are the ratings from the [Onsemi 2N7000 datasheet](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/ONSM/ONSM-S-A0013670144/ONSM-S-A0013669918-1.pdf?hkey=6D3A4C79FDBF58556ACFDE234799DDF0):

[image]

The entry \$V_{GSS}\$ is telling you that you should never allow gate potential to differ from source potential (above or below) by more than 20V.

The next table is from the [Vishay Si8424 datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/74400/si8424db.pdf). The parameter name here is \$V_{GS}\$, and this device is more "fragile" in this respect. It will suffer damage if the potential difference between gate and source exceeds 5V in either direction:

[image]

This doesn't mean you *have* to use 20V, or 5V. Later on in the datasheets there are other tables, which include the \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ parameter:

2N7000:

[image]

Si8424:

[image]

There's some uncertainty here, so you'll usually work with worst case values. For example, for the 2N7000, the manufacturer guarantees that  \$V_{GS}=3V\$ will begin to switch on the MOSFET. As \$V_{GS}\$ falls through 0.8V, the device will certainly begin to switch off.

Keep in mind, this value of \$V_{GS}\$ is where the channel *begins* to conduct, bit it will still have significant channel resistance \$R_{DS}\$. If you want to have the transistor conduct as well as it can, you should aim for a \$V_{GS}\$ significantly greater than this threshold value. How much greater? Well, you should refer to the various graphs that also appear in the datasheets, to find out what conditions to expect for various \$V_{GS}\$, like this one, for the 2N7000:

[image]

This particular graph contains enough information for you to determine a lot about how it will behave under various conditions (including channel resistance, from the \$\frac{dV}{dI}\$ slope), but different datasheets will present such information in different forms.

So, for the 2N7000, if you want the device to be switched off, you must ensure that gate potential (relative to source potential) is well under 0.8V, preferably zero, or even negative. To switch the device on, \$V_{GS}\$ must be well over 3V, the higher the better, but exactly how much higher requires you to consult the graphs. Under no circumstances should you ever allow the gate to exceed 20V higher in potential than the source, or 20V lower.

Comment: "it's usually better to set VGS as high as possible, without being so large that it damages the transistor" -- emphasis on "usually": an example where it's not, might be a high-frequency switching application where Vgs > 8V has incremental or no benefit, and using Vgs in the 15-20V range more than doubles the control power dissipation; that can be the difference between a successful design and an overheated controller.

Answer (score 3):

In most applications the VGS(th) is only confusing.  It is measured at 100uA or 10uA or some very low current.  In switching applications **forget** the threshold voltage.

1. look at the max voltage for the Gate.  Often +/-20V.  Never go past these voltages.
2. look at the DS voltage verses D current at different VGS graph. If you want to switch 10A peak then choose a on voltage that closes the transistor very well. (most important)
3. do not let the part stay near the Gate threshold voltage for any amount of time. Switch from 0V to 15V fast, not staying at 2V for more than nano Seconds.
4. watch out for new transistors that have very different G voltages.  I am using parts with 0.9V threshold voltage and +6V/-1 max.  I am driving at 5V.